# Sprite Kit physics on word rotation - collision and gravity Sprite-kit

Tags: ios, rotation, sprite-kit, physics

I'm working on a new project and I am completely stuck with the main character movements.

The picture at this link explain my situation 
http://www.chr.to/stuck.jpg

I have a world (black) a character (red) and an obstacle

The character and the world are children of SELF
The obstacle is a world's child

My goal is to move the character around the world but it must be in the same position all the time, just the world must turn below its feet.

To achieve this, I rotate the world in the opposite direction of the character direction and the effect is perfect (I get direction from a joystick)

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

rotation = rotation + input;
wordTest.zRotation = rotation; }
```

The biggest problem is when I found an object in the world.

The character and all obstacles are physics objects.

When the character hit an obstacle it drags off the world because the rotation continues and It can't keep its position in the middle of the screen .

Probably it's not the best approach, I have to find the way to stop the rotation...
or Do you have a better suggestion?

thank you guys

Comment: You will need to set the character's collisionBitMask as zero and handle the rotation from the contact delegate

Comment: But I need the physic contact between objects...for example if the character jumps on an obstacle

Comment: You want to stop the world from rotating if the character is hit by the object?

Comment: yes but I also need to jump on obstacles

Answer (score 0):

Set up a `BOOL` flag called `canRotate`, and use it to check whether rotation must be applied in the `-update` method.

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    if (canRotate)
    {
        rotation = rotation + input;
        wordTest.zRotation = rotation;
    }
}
```

Set this flag as YES in the `-init` method and, when a contact between the character and obstacle is triggered in `-didBeginContact`, set the flag to NO.